# Using System.Transaction how to update multiple rows in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to use `System.Transactions` and update multiple rows. My database is connected using Entity Framework.

Below is the code I tried but it throws an error :

```
public  void Update(List<PortfolioCompanyLinkModel> record)
{
    var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        foreach (var item in record)
        {
            var portfolioCompanyLink = _context.PortfolioCompanyLink.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == item.Id);
            portfolioCompanyLink.ModifiedBy = _loggedInUser;
            portfolioCompanyLink.ModifiedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
            portfolioCompanyLink.URL = item.URL;

            _context.SaveChanges();
            //_context.PortfolioCompanyLink.Update(portfolioCompanyLink);
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Error:

> The configured execution strategy 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy' does not support user initiated transactions. Use the execution strategy returned by 'DbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy()' to execute all the operations in the transaction as a retriable unit.

Can someone help me on how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You problem is the `SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy` [as described in Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-resiliency/retry-logic?redirectedfrom=MSDN#solution-manually-call-execution-strategy)

> When **not** using a retrying execution strategy you can wrap multiple operations in a single transaction. For example, the following code wraps two SaveChanges calls in a single transaction. If any part of either operation fails then none of the changes are applied.

[MS docs on resiliency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-resilient-entity-framework-core-sql-connections)

> System.InvalidOperationException: The configured execution strategy 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy' does not support user initiated transactions. Use the execution strategy returned by 'DbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy()' to execute all the operations in the transaction as a retriable unit.

#### Solution: Manually Call Execution Strategy

```
var executionStrategy = _context.db.CreateExecutionStrategy();

executionStrategy.Execute(
    () =>
    {
        // execute your logic here
        using(var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var item in record)
                {
                    var portfolioCompanyLink = _context.PortfolioCompanyLink.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == item.Id);
                    portfolioCompanyLink.ModifiedBy = _loggedInUser;
                    portfolioCompanyLink.ModifiedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    portfolioCompanyLink.URL = item.URL;
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    //_context.PortfolioCompanyLink.Update(portfolioCompanyLink);
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    });
```

You can set the strategy globally too, but that depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: which library i have to use for DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.defaultexecutionstrategy?view=entity-framework-6.2.0 It's `DefaultExecutionStrategy`, my mistake.

Comment: Is there any way to update using system.transactions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions

Comment: Yes, you just need to surround with the proper strategy. In the answer you can see `using(var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
        {`

Comment: even if i use this is it necessary to use DefaultExecutionStrategy?

Comment: Yes, because the transaction does not know if it can retry all or some of the commands. So you either set the strategy to non-retry when you have multiple commands, or the overall strategy to non-retry for single commands too.

Comment: I tried installing using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure this package but i am still getting error saying the type or namespace DefaultExecutionStrategy acnnot be found

Comment: Is it not possible without updating?

Comment: What do you mean by without updating?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205062/discussion-between-harsha-mullangi-and-athanasios-kataras).

Answer (score 0):

Ive struggled with this for a few weeks and decided to share my solution, to broadly use in our library

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
    
public class Transactions {

    private Transactions() {}

    public static void Run(DbContext dbContext, Func<IDbContextTransaction, bool> act) {
        if(dbContext != null && act != null) {
            var executionStrategy = dbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();

            executionStrategy.Execute(() => {
                
                using var ret = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
                if(ret != null) {
                    
                    try {
                        if(act.Invoke(ret)) {
                            ret.Commit();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        ret.Rollback();
                        throw new Exception("Error during transaction, rolling back");
                    }

                } else {
                    throw new Exception("Error while starting transaction");
                }

            });
        }
    }

}
```

So one might use it like this

```
Transactions.Run(dbContext, (trans) => {

    trackedEntity.property = "updated valued";
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    return true; // this is to give some control over the transaction if needed, so one might use savepoints etc

});
```