# I use SaveChanges and get an error shown in the question

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
using (var transaction = await _companyContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
{
    _companyContext.Set<CURRENT_T>().Add(newEntity);
    _companyContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT CURRENT_T ON;");

    await _companyContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    _companyContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT CURRENT_T OFF");
    await transaction.CommitAsync();
}
```

> I'm having difficulty solving the above error, do you think I can fix the problem if I make any changes to the code I shared?

I'm getting the error on the line that starts with :

```
await _companyContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This is the error:

> InvalidOperationException: The configured execution strategy 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy' does not support user-initiated transactions.
> Use the execution strategy returned by 'DbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy()' to execute all the operations in the transaction as a retryable unit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using System.Transaction how to update multiple rows in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526881/using-system-transaction-how-to-update-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework)

Comment: I looked for this question and couldn't find my answer.

Comment: Well it clearly has to do something with the fact that you are not using "DbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy()" as also stated in the exception. Have you tried adding it?

Comment: I tried but this time I got compiler error.

Comment: Maybe the first question should be: why do you want to turn on `IDENTITY_INSERT`? That's suggests an underlying problem that should be solved first.